# Adding a style element within another element and having the styles only apply to the parent?

Tags: html, css

Suppose a generated fragment of HTML and CSS where the CSS should not apply outside of the fragment.

```
<div class="text">I am outside and should not be red.</div>
<div>
  <div class="text">I am inside and should be red.</div>

  <style type="text/css">
    .text {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</div>
```

Which produces:

[image: example]

How can the `<style>` tag be altered to only apply to its containing element (`<div>`) and its children? Consider that a unique id/class cannot be used, so this solution is not valid in this case, although it would naturally produce the desired result:

```
<div class="text">I am outside and should not be red.</div>
<div class="sandbox">
  <div class="text">I am inside and should be red.</div>

  <style type="text/css">
    .sandbox .text {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</div>
```

The HTML and Style (and JS) will be entered standalone and will be wrapped and injected into the DOM at-will. So the goal is that this injected chunk is "sandboxed" to the outermost element of the chunk. And I don't want to depend on the author to correctly apply unique selectors to all of their CSS classes -- you know, because people make mistakes. Instead, I want to automatically scope the  within the chunk to the generated parent element which contains it.

Suppose the "chunk" is as below:

```
<div class="text">I am inside and should be red.</div>

<style type="text/css">
  .text {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

The "server" would return a wrapped chunk like this (note the wrapper `<div>`):

```
<div>
  <div class="text">I am inside and should be red.</div>

  <style type="text/css">
    .text {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</div>
```

The part that is missing is how to "scope" any `<style>` elements within the chunk so they only apply to the wrapper.

It appears that this used to be possible via the `scoped` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#attr-scoped), but it is deprecated. It appears that I can polyfill this feature, which is what I will do for now, but I am curious if there is another solution.

Comment: Maybe shadow dom?

Comment: what can you modify (if you can't add custom class/id)? can you just do something like `div>div.text....`?

Comment: I suppose in this particular case you could use div>div.text or .text:first-of-type or .text:last-of-type or a variety of nth selectors.  but if it's scaling and not just for this example it may be a bit harder.

Comment: The HTML and Style (and JS) will be entered standalone and will be wrapped and injected into the DOM at-will. So the goal is that this injected chunk is "sandboxed" to the outermost element of the chunk. And I don't want to depend on the author to correctly apply unique selectors to all of their CSS classes -- you know, because people make mistakes. Instead, I want to automatically scope the `<style>` within the chunk to the generated parent element which contains it.

Comment: Note that whomever edited the question to split the HTML/CSS changed the meaning of the question. I've reverted that change.

Comment: I edited your question and aside from making your code runnable, no other changes were made. The edit history shows that clearly.

Comment: @j08691 you removed the `<style>` element entirely and moved the contained CSS out of the parent element. This completes changes the question.

Comment: Putting a style tag inline (instead of in the `<head>` where it belongs) is invalid HTML. Most browsers will still render it anyway, but it will be applied as if it were declared properly. Also note that the `type` attribute for the style element is not needed and should be omitted.

Comment: That's true. But you still altered the question. Let's move on.

Comment: In the absence of scoped I think you'll have to resort to JS - would that be allowed?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), `>`:

```css
div > div.text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">I am outside and should not be red.</div>
<div>
  <div class="text">I am inside and should be red.</div>
</div>
```

You could get even more specific by using the sibling (`+`) and child (`>`) combinators together:

```css
div.text+div>div.text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">I am outside and should not be red.</div>
<div>
  <div class="text">I am inside and should be red.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I probably was not clear enough in the question. Please see my explanatory comment (also updating the question text).

Comment: Note that whomever edited the question to split the HTML/CSS changed the meaning of the question. I've reverted that change.